# ChartJs Memory Leak | Garbage Collection does not clean Chart Object or Arrays after render

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, chart.js

I am working on project where I have to create huge number of charts using chartJs. I noticed my page kept crashing when the number of charts rose upto 1000(will vary depending on memory of the machine).

After exploring the issue further using chrome devtools it seems once the charts are created they are not garbage collected. Each chart Object and the arrays created by the object (labels array, datasets array within which is data array) are retained in the memory and they stay in memory and are not garbage collected. Since they are not garbage collected when number of charts in a page reaches its peek after a while page crashes since it reaches memory limit.

How do fix this memory leak or trigger garbage collection?

Edit: Please note I do not want to remove the charts that are generated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rb0f32vz/10/) for cleaner view

Scripts for generating chart are as follows

```
var COLORS = ["#265b62", "#FF6361", "#FFA600", "#66C2A4", "#EF3B2C",
        "#67000D", "#349866", "#A05195", "#78C679", "#2B8CBE",
        "#8C96C6", "#373F52", "#810F7C", "#BC5090", "#FF3D67",
        "#D5B029", "#CD9B9A", "#EC7014", "#665191", "#003F5C"];

    function getLabels(numberOfLabel) {
        var labels = [];

        for (var i=1; i<= numberOfLabel; i++) {
            labels.push('Category '+i);
        }

        return labels;
    }

    function getDataSeries(labels, numberOfSeries) {

        var dataSeries = [];
        for (var i=1; i<= numberOfSeries; i++) {
            dataSeries.push(getDataObj(i, labels.length));
        }

        return dataSeries;
    }

    function getDataObj(count, numberOfLabel) {
        var seriesLabel = 'Dataset ' + count;
        var colorName = COLORS[count % COLORS.length];

        dataArray = [];

        for (var i=1; i<= numberOfLabel; i++) {
            dataArray.push(randomScalingFactor());
        }

        var dataObj = {
            label: seriesLabel,
            backgroundColor: colorName,
            borderColor: colorName,
            data: dataArray,
            fill: false,
        };

        return dataObj;
    }

    function getConfig(chartCount, dataPoints, barOrLineCounts) {
        var chartLabels = getLabels(dataPoints);
        var dataSeries = getDataSeries(chartLabels, barOrLineCounts);

        var chartTitle = 'Chart.js Line Chart Count ' + chartCount;
        var chartType = 'line';
        var config = {
            type: chartType,
            data: {
                labels: chartLabels,
                datasets: dataSeries
            },
            options: {
                // ===============performance tweaks==========================================
                parsing: false,
                spanGaps: true,
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        tension: 0, // disables bezier curves for line datasets
                        fill: false,
                        stepped: false,
                        borderDash: []
                    },
                    point: {
                        radius: 2 // default = 3, set 0 to disable and gain performance
                    }
                },
                animation: false,
                // ===============performance tweaks==========================================
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: chartTitle,
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            autoSkip: false,
                            maxRotation: 45,
                            minRotation: 45,
                            sampleSize: 35
                        },
                        stacked: chartType === 'bar',
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            // setting min and max will gain performance as chartjs wont have to compute this.
                            min: 0,
                            max: 100
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        };

        return config;
    }


    function generateCharts(chartCount, dataPoints, barOrLineCounts) {
        for (var i=1; i<= chartCount; i++) {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas'+i).getContext('2d');

            var myLine = new Chart(ctx, getConfig(i, dataPoints, barOrLineCounts));
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {

                var chartCount = 1;
        var dataPoints= 20;
        var barOrLineCounts = 10;


        $('#chartType').val("${chartType}");

        generateCharts(chartCount, dataPoints, barOrLineCounts);
    };

    var xCount =  2;
    function addChart() {
        var chartCount = 1;
        var dataPoints= 20;
        var barOrLineCounts = 10;

        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas'+xCount).getContext('2d');
        var myLine = new Chart(ctx, getConfig(xCount, dataPoints, barOrLineCounts));

        xCount = xCount + 1;
    }

    function randomScalingFactor() {
        return Math.random() * 100;
    }
```

Sample HTML for test case.

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <button id="addChart" onclick="addChart()">Add Chart</button><br><br>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="chart1" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas1">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart2" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas2">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart3" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas3">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart4" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas4">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart5" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas4">
         </canvas>
      </div>
...
...
...
      <div id="chart17" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas17">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart18" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas18">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart19" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas19">
         </canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="chart20" class="col-sm-12">
         <canvas id="canvas20">
         </canvas>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Facing this issue when use antd g2plot gauge as well. It is really weird that the charts objects memory grow when re-render......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your charts to be garbage-collected, you must make sure that there are no remaining references to them.

Use `chartInstance.destroy()` to clean up Chart.js's internal references to the chart object: [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy)

When you call `new Chart(...)`, you will have to store that reference somewhere (e.g. in an array) and call `.destroy()` on it when you're done.  Don't forget to remove the reference from the array as well.

Comment: calling `.destroy()` removes the chart from the page/view, which I do not want. I want to keep the charts that I generate. I want the chart objects and the arrays associated with the object to be garbage collected once chart is drawn in the canvas.

Comment: You can save the contents of the canvas, destroy the chart, and restore the canvas.  That will remove interactivity though.  Is that ok?  If you're ok with an image it may be simpler to use a rendering service like quickchart.io (an open source project of mine)

Comment: can you suggest how I can do what you are suggesting? I can it as img using .toBase64Image() of chartJs but that didn't help much with memory issue.

Comment: Calling destroy removes the image, so if you want to keep the non-interactive chart images you can save it with `toBase64Image`.  If you can't afford the memory to even display the chart images, then you should use a third party rendering service such as QuickChart.

Comment: i understand your concept. However I am interested to know if I wanted to keep the charts interactive is there a way I can trigger garbage collection for associated objects and arrays once the chart is rendered? or they have to remain in memory for the interactivity?

Comment: The chart object and its associated data and event listeners, etc, must remain in memory for interactivity.

Comment: Quite strange to see that chart is accumulating memory whenever state updates...